# I installed tailwind css using its own guide. I want to use the background className (`bg-black`) which is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I installed tailwind css using its own guide `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer npx tailwindcss init -p`
I want to use the background className (`bg-black`) which is not working

Directory file path:
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COERs.png)

in `src/styles/global.css`

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

in `tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

in `src/pages/index.js`

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className='bg-black'>
        Home
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

The HTML in browser result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBJ69.png)

I tried

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

but I am expecting
[home with background black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1nNt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the global.css too if you want Tailwindcss to work.

`import styles from '@/styles/global.css'`